# how to insert data into logged in user column using php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Maybe the question isn't clear enough.
I have the table **users** that has username, email, password, and orderID.
Once a user is logged in, he can access a page where he can click a button that means that the user confirms the order and generates a random string that is displayed to the user.
This is done by Javascript:

```
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
}
randomstring=randomstring.fontsize("6");
randomstring=randomstring.bold();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your order id is: "+ randomstring;
}
```

The Simple HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6"><button  onclick="randomString()">Rezervo</button></div>
  <div class="span6"><p id="demo"></p></div>
</div>
```

Everything works great, but how can the logged in user insert this generated code in his orderID column in the database when the button is clicked? 
Please help me.
Sorry for bad english. Not my first language.

Comment: You must use some server side language like php. Than you can make an AJAX call to some php script that will insert it into database.

Comment: Either form submit or ajax.

Comment: I am new to php, but i managed to do the register-verify-login.
any tip on how to actually code it with php? or even ajax? any reference?

Comment: Go through some tutorials concerning php, js, ajax ... will flag this as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many database extensions that you can use to connect to your database. You can add PHP logic to your .html file so that after the button is clicked, you connect to your database, make a query (like an INSERT), and then close the connection.

Some references to get your started:

- http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php (PHP Database extensions)
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/ (PHP Tutorials)
- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL (Not overly relevant to what you want to do, but the snippets of code show you roughly how it works)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it different way.
On click of that button

1. either submit the page & on submit of the page insert order id into database
2. Or implement ajax functionality, so that page will not submit, but on ajax call you will save the data into database

Comment: do you have any sample so i can see?

Comment: Regarding Ajax you can check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_quick_guide.htm